# Change another Tag Css When input Has Value

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i have this tags in to my project, but i want to change css `placeholder` tag color and size ... style when my input has value.
i want To Use `:valid` in css but I will not succeed.
tip: my HTML Tags Structure Cant Change

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" required>
</div>
<span class="placeholder">E-Mail</span>
```

my Css:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 40px;
}

.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 1px;
  top: 2px;
  transition: 0.1s ease all;
}

input:focus~.placeholder {
  top: -1px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

input[value=""]~.placeholder {
  top: -1px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

Comment: You are going to need JavaScript for this, is that acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done purely through CSS with any amount of cross-browser compatibility (yet), because the element you want to style is not a sibling, or the descendant of a sibling, of the element the changed style is a response to.

There are a couple of ways, though, if JavaScript is an option:

```js
// simple named function to determine if the <input> element (evt.currentTarget)
// has a valid value:
const hasValue = (evt) => {
    // caching the current <input> element to which the event-handler is bound:
    let target = evt.currentTarget;
    
    // navigating to the closest ancestor element with a class of 'wrapper',
    // using the Element.classList API to toggle the class of 'childInputHasValue'
    // on the element based on whether the <input> has a valid value, in that it
    // matches the regular expression in the 'pattern' attribute:
    target.closest('.wrapper').classList.toggle('childInputHasValue', target.validity.valid)
  },
  // retrieving all <input> elements with a type attribute equal to 'text':
  inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');

// iterating over the <input> elements using an anonymous Arrow function with
// NodeList.prototype.forEach():
inputs.forEach(
  // binding the 'hasValue' function as the event-handler for the 'input' event
  // on each of the <input> elements:
  (el) => el.addEventListener('input', hasValue)
);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.placeholder {
  color: crimson;
}

.wrapper.childInputHasValue + .placeholder {
  color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\s]{5,20}$">
</div>
<span class="placeholder">E-Mail</span>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t91y4vp2/).

Alternatively, if you're able to adjust your HTML to the following this *can* be done – quite easily – with CSS:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.placeholder {
  color: crimson
}

input[type=text]:valid + .placeholder {
  color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\s]{5,20}$">
  <span class="placeholder">E-Mail</span>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t91y4vp2/1/).

However, if you're okay with (currently) poor cross-browser performance (as I write this `:has()` is available only in Safari and behind the "Experimental Web Platform features" flag in Chrome and Chromium), possibly using a JS shim if necessary, then you *may* be able to use the `:has()` selector:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.placeholder {
  color: crimson;
}

.wrapper:has(input:valid) + .placeholder {
  color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\s]{5,20}$">
</div>
<span class="placeholder">E-Mail</span>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t91y4vp2/2/).

As for using `:has()` with a shim, that could be as simple as follows:

```js
// here we check if the browser supports the ':has(input:valid)' selector, note that this is achieved
// by passing the 'selector(...)' CSS function into the CSS.supports() method with the selector for
// which we're assessing support:
if (!CSS.supports('selector(:has(input:valid))')) {
  const hasValue = (evt) => {
      let target = evt.currentTarget;
      target.closest('.wrapper').classList.toggle('childInputHasValue', target.validity.valid);
    },
    inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');

  inputs.forEach(
    (el) => el.addEventListener('input', hasValue)
  );
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.placeholder {
  color: crimson;
}

/* this selector will be used by browsers that understand, and
   implement, the ':has(...)' selector, and discarded by others: */
.wrapper:has(input:valid) + .placeholder {
  color: lime;
}

/* this selector will take advantage of the classes/approach
   implemented by JavaScript: */
.wrapper.childInputHasValue + .placeholder {
  color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\s]{5,20}$">
</div>
<span class="placeholder">E-Mail</span>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t91y4vp2/3/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [Adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).
  - [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) ([compatibility](https://caniuse.com/css-has)).
  - [`@supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports).
- HTML:

  - [`pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern).
  - [`required` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`CSS.supports()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: yes, this is my answer Great And Complete

Comment: I'm glad to have helped; if you feel that this is the correct answer consider clicking on the check-mark (✓) to the left of my answer, this let's the system - and other users - know that the question has been answered. It's not obligatory to do so, and should only ever be fine if your question has been answered to your satisfaction by the answer you accept.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, but I feel it might not hurt to mention the general sibling combinator (~) as opposed to just the adjacent sibling combinator (+). 

I can definitely see cases where you want to check the input of a non-adjacent sibling (e.g. even a <br/> is going to stop the adjacent sibling combinator from working.)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible by CSS only. You have to add a toggle class on the parent wrapper when input is focused, then there will add a class like active in the wrapper and you could write CSS like-

```
    wrapper.active ~ .placeholder {
    top: -1px;
      font-size: 11px;
    }
```

Comment: This wrong not my answer

Comment: When the input is focused you can use focus-within on its parent and thus alter the CSS for the element with placeholder class. However, it loses this pseudo class when the user goes off to focus on another element.